# Autocomplete house number with Google api

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have a custom address input form, and perfofrm requests for Google Place API from my back-end to autocomplete user's input, but i can't get house numbers by the street. I performed requests like that:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1 Lenin Avenue, Tomsk, Tomsk Oblast, Russia&strictbounds=true&location=56.488430, 84.948047&radius=12285.769883&types=address
```

I expected some results like:

```
"Lenin Avenue, 1, Tomsk, Tomsk Oblast, Russia"
"Lenin Avenue, 10, Tomsk, Tomsk Oblast, Russia"
"Lenin Avenue, 11, Tomsk, Tomsk Oblast, Russia"
"Lenin Avenue, 12, Tomsk, Tomsk Oblast, Russia"
etc.
```

But got only first result. I tried to use "*components*" paremeter, but API accepted only "*country:XX*" filter, also tried using masks like "1* Lenin Avenue, Tomsk, Tomsk Oblast, Russia".

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use **[Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details)** to get the full details of the address you are trying to search.

I tried the address in your Place Autocomplete request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1%20Lenin%20Avenue,%20Tomsk,%20Tomsk%20Oblast,%20Russia&strictbounds=true&location=56.488430,%2084.948047&radius=12285.769883&types=address&key=YOUR_KEY

the first result returned this **place_id: ChIJE93JfarsJkMRQlvoCf2L0Tc**

I used that place_id in my Place Details request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJE93JfarsJkMRQlvoCf2L0Tc&key=YOUR_KEY

And I was able to get this result including the street_number:

```
"address_components": [
{
"long_name": "1",
"short_name": "1",
"types": [
"street_number"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Lenin Avenue",
"short_name": "Lenin Ave",
"types": [
"route"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Tomsk",
"short_name": "Tomsk",
"types": [
"locality",
"political"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Tomsk",
"short_name": "Tomsk",
"types": [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Tomskaya oblast'",
"short_name": "Tomskaya oblast'",
"types": [
"administrative_area_level_1",
"political"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Russia",
"short_name": "RU",
"types": [
"country",
"political"
]
},
{
"long_name": "634028",
"short_name": "634028",
"types": [
"postal_code"
]
}
]
```

Comment: It helps to find details about single house, but I need to get all houses in a root which numbers begin from specific digit.